# High difference between cv rate and classification accuracy in libsvm

Tags: machine-learning, svm, cross-validation, libsvm

edit: nevermind I solved it

I am training an svm on a dataset with 5 classes using libsvm. I have a training set and a test set. I am using the easy.py script. 
The accuracy is a lot worse than the cv rate (accuracy 52%, cv rate 81%). What can be the reason for that difference?

Unlike [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179171/libsvm-easy-py-and-grid-py-doing-worse-that-svm-train), I have 200 features and 2000 examples

More info about libsvm https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf
easy.py is a script that automatically finds the best set of parameters doing grid search and computes the test accuracy

Comment: What does CV rate measure? Is it CV accuracy?

Comment: cross validation rate. easy.py does grid search to find the best set of parameters and makes a prediction using these parameters at test time. Yes it is cv accuracy

Comment: So what's accuracy, then?

Comment: Could you edit your question to explain this in more detail? In particular, to remove the reference to easy.py and replace it with a description of what you're doing and how you're measuring these quantities. Anyone can have a file on their computer called easy.py and it's probably not the one you're using!

Comment: Maybe, but CV is not a community that does debugging. If you're interested in the statistical properties of some algorithm, that's on-topic here. If you think there's a bug or a problem with your code, that's not, but perhaps will be on SO.SE or Programmers.SE. The help centers will describe this in more detail.

Comment: @user777 thanks for trying to help. I fixed my issue

Comment: Perhaps you could post an answer explaining what you found. Future users would benefit.